# android:screenOrientation tag in application does not work

Tags: android, screen-orientation

The `android:screenOrientation` tag when placed in `<application>` does not work.
But when I put `android:screenOrientation` in a `<activity>` tag it works.

If `android:screenOrientation` tag works in `<application>` then, there would no need to put `android:screenOrientation` handling for every activity.

I wonder, why there is such strange behavior in Android platform for `screenOrientation` tag?

Comment: when placed in .. what? water ? ;)

Comment: Please rephrase your question.

Comment: I believe he is asking why screenOrientation is NOT an attibute of <application> but only <activity>. Zoombie?

Comment: we can put android:screenOrientation="portrait" in <application> right? and also in <activity> .  If i put android:screenOrientation="portrait" in <application> then application still allows landscape orientation when phone/emulator rotated. When android:screenOrientation="portrait" placed in each activity of application, it allows only portrait mode. So my question is android why not allows on portrait mode for every activity of application when android:screenOrientation="portrait" placed in <application> tag.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `<application>` element does not support `android:screenOrientation`. You can tell this by [reading the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html).

As to why it is not supported in the `<application>` element, I imagine it is at least in part because you should not be using it on many activities, and perhaps not all activities.

For example, your proposed `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` simply should not be done, pretty much ever. `landscape` I can understand, for certain types of activities (cameras, video players, some games). But `portrait` means:

- You do not want users to be able to use their side-slider hardware keyboards
- You do not want users to be able to use their tablets in the Android-natural landscape orientation
- You do not want to run on Google TV

`android:screenOrientation` should be used only on those activities that absolutely positively *have* to be in that orientation. Otherwise, please respect your users' wishes as to which orientation to use. Not allowing you to set it for the application as a whole is simply one way to help ensure that you actually think about whether it is needed for a given activity or not.