# Android screen orientation change have different behaviour on tablet

Tags: android, screen, orientation, tablet

I have activity with:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

and code:

```
if(blah blah blah)
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
```

in activity onCreate.
1. When test on smartphone "setRequestedOrientation" causes destroy activity and create again with desired screen orientation.
2. When test on tablet device this code runs only once activity. After "setRequestedOrientation" it just continues without destroy and create again activity. This happens when start code without debuger or without breakpoint in onCreate. If I stop in onCreate function - I see in logs - destroying and onCreate again.
How to catch specific situation with tablet?

UPDATE:
- Problem with tablet occurs when 'Orientation lock' if off. If 'Orientation lock' is enabled program works in same way as in smartphone.

UPDATE2:
- Is it possible to set preffered screen orientation to whole application. So when activity starts to know desired orientation. This will make unnessesary call 'setScreenOrientation' and avoid second activity creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.. you **cannot set preffered screen orientation for whole application**... instead you should call for setScreenOrientation in respective activies only... [Refere this link here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062722/androidscreenorientation-tag-in-application-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1):

After whole day spent with this issue I made following changes in my application:
1. Every activity /without first/ are declared as android:screenOrientation="behind".
2. In first activity I set preferred screen orientation using user selected mode /from my menu.
3. I call setRequestedOrientation only when user changed mode in my menu options.

This causes activities to be created only once. Finaly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
<activity ActivityName = "test_activity"
android:configChanges="orientation">
</activity>
```

in your android manifest file. It will not allow activity to restart on orientation change but onconfigurationchange will be called normaly.
Later you can getdisplayorientation in onconfigurationchange and set whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks. I know this way. Google strongly recomended to not do this.