# Android Orientation Lock

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-orientation

I have a small requirement in my Android project.

1. My application should run **Landscape** in **tablet** and **Portrait** in **Phone**
2. Is there any way to lock orientation in Application, instead of setting in Activity.

Comment: android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: @RohitGoswami What will be the orientation in Tablet if we lock with orientation portrait

Comment: You can find the size of your device by using display metrics and then you can set orientation for tablet and phone

Answer (score 1):

You can check screen size following tis piece of code :

```
    public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}
```

Than set orientation :

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: yes ) that's the point of different activity - different configuration.

Comment: Thank You. Is there anyway to handle globally (i.e instead of setting orientation in every activity, any other wok around to set for Application? )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297326/android-screen-orientation-change-have-different-behaviour-on-tablet

Answer (score 1):

To avoid calculation for screen size you can instead use Boolean in dimens like

in `values-sw600dp/bools.xml -> <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>`

```
values-sw720dp/bools.xml -> <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
```

and simple `values/bools -> <bool name="isTablet">false</bool>`

Then in activity you can simple set

```
boolean isTablet = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
        if (isTablet) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Note this will only work for `API level 3.2` and above.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels > getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels)
    {
        bLandscape = true;
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        //initViews_Land();
    }
    else
    {
        bLandscape = false;
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        //initViews_Port();
    }
```

one way is to use this code is each of your activity.

> Another way is to create two different projects for Phone and Tablet. Upload two APKs (Tablet APK must have higher version number) and activate both of them in Advanced mode. Play Store will manage it automatically depending on device it is being installed

**Phone Manifest:** All activities must have  android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"

```
...
<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
...
```

**Tablet Manifest:** All activities must have  android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"

```
...
<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
...
```

hope it might help