# How to fix screen orientation to portrait mode for smartphone in android using only application class.

Tags: android, screen, android-orientation, portrait

How to set screen orientation to portrait only mode for smart phone and both orientation(port and land) for tablet in single apk(project) in android using only application class.

Use of

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

in all the activity is one option . I need a `api` to set fixed orientation at application level..

Comment: May I ask why you prefer doing this in the Application class? You can always put it in one activity and have all your other activities inherit from it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062722/androidscreenorientation-tag-in-application-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

```
Activity activity = new MainActivity();
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: One does not simply create an activity with its constructor, even if you are god :p

Comment: @LawrenceChoy : did you try creating a constructor or just commenting with a wild guess? The person who asked this question wants to create it in Application class. Then how would you be able to change the orientation without an instance of any activity class [ofcourse without doing it from the manifest file] :) if you know the answer , please post it instead of wasting time commenting on other's answers :)

Comment: Most of the time, activity is used by using `Intent` to start it. No constructor will be used, and usually no reference to that activity is available too. I do not consider my previous comment as "wasting time", because although it does not answer the original question, it might help someone who had problems regarding activity usage:)